# What is the Taylor series of $e^x$ centred at $3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{e^3}{n!}(x-3)^n
$$

This is my answer - is it correct?

Comment: I think you want the sum as n goes from 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: Yup looks right, you just need an infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up your indexing ($k$ doesn't appear in your summand and the upper limit must be $\infty$), but the terms are okay. The correct representation would be
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^3}{n!} (x-3)^n$$
Derivation is pretty straight-forward using the known expansion at $0$ and $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$:
$$e^x = e^{3+(x-3)} = e^3 e^{x-3} = e^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-3)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^3}{n!} (x-3)^n$$

Comment: Correct! And why? :-)

Comment: @Ant I was in the process of adding a very simple proof. Or what do you mean?

Comment: That! Perfect :-)